Help with Bernstein’s inequality for a disc
I'm trying to understand the proof of Bernstein’s inequality for a disc on page 30 of Wolff's notes on Harmonic analysis but I'm not able to follow the steps.
From the previous theorem, we know that $\phi \in \mathcal{S}$ (Schwartz space) such that $\hat{\phi}$ is equal to $1$  on $D(0, 1)$ (the disk of radius $1$ centered at $0$). We also have, if I understand correctly, $\phi^{R^{-1}}(x) = \phi(R^{-1}x)$.  So, the first step says that if $\psi = \phi^{R^{-1}}$ then
$$\| \psi \|_r = \| \phi\|_r R^{n/r'}$$
(where $1/r + 1/r' = 1$). But, I'm not able to show this. I've tried to calculate this directly
$$\| \psi \|_r^r = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \psi(x)^rdx = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi(R^{-1}x)^rdx.$$
Substituting $y = R^{-1}x$ we get this is
$$R\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \phi(Rx)^rdx = \| \phi \|_r^r R \Rightarrow \| \psi \|_r = \| \phi \|_r R^{1/r.}$$
But, this is not what the notes claim so I'm a bit lost.

Actually, I realized I made some mistakes.
From the previous theorem, we actually know that $\phi \in \mathcal{S}$ (Schwartz space) such that $\hat{\phi}$ is equal to $1$  on $D(0, 1)$ (the disk of radius $1$ centered at $0$). We also have, if I understand correctly, $\phi^{R^{-1}}(x) = R^n\phi(R^{-1}x)$ (where we are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$).  So, the first step says that if $\psi = \phi^{R^{-1}}$ then
$$\| \psi \|_r = \| \phi\|_r R^{n/r'}$$
(where $1/r + 1/r' = 1$). Calculating directly we get
$$\| \psi \|_r^r = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left| R^n\phi(Rx) \right|^r dx = R^{nr} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left| \phi(Rx) \right|^r dx = R^{n(r - 1)} \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \left| \phi(y) \right|^r dy = \| \phi \|_r^r R^{n(r-1)}$$
where, in the second to last last step, we used $y = Rx$.
Taking the $r$th root of both side, we get
$$\| \psi \|_r = \phi \|_r R^{n(r-1)/r} = \phi \|_r R^{n/r'}$$
as we want!

Looks all right. It is "just" a matter of scaling. Notations in that book get crazy pretty fast! It is a fundamental resource though. I also suffered on it and presumably will suffer again in the future.

Thanks! I'm still struggling with this proof - I'm going to post a separate question on this though.
